# SSRS "There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe" error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017 on my computer and am having issues with SSRS.  I previously had 2016, which worked fine, but I had to reinstall the OS on my system and only found 2017 to download.  When I try to preview a report on SSRS locally I get the error:

"There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PreviewProcessingService9512/ReportProcessing 
that could accept the message.  This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action."

I've read other people suggesting to right click the .rdl and click run, but if I do that I get a reporting services error "The item cannot be found."  I've also read that the Net.Pipe Listener Adapter needs to be restarted, but this isn't even installed on my machine and I don't see where to install it.  I've experimented and found that if I create a new user in SQL Server and grant it administrator privileges then the report preview will work for a short time, maybe 15-60 minutes, before going back to the "endpoint" error.  I've even tried uninstalling and reinstalling both SQL Server and Visual Studio, but I get the same problems.

I'm completely stuck here.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a permissions issue.  Even though I was logged in as an administrator I need to run Visual Studio under the "run as administrator" mode.  This doesn't make sense as I'm logged in as an admin, but at least it works.